# Call function if switch gets toggled in VueJS/VuetifyJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toggle, vuetify.js

I'm using [VuetifyJS](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls) for VueJS and I need to call a function if the switch gets toggled. How to do that?

Template:

```
 <v-container fluid>
    <v-switch :label="`Switch 1: ${switch1.toString()}`" v-model="switch1"></v-switch>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        switch1: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set up a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `switch1` data property as follows:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        switch1: false
      }
    },
    watch: {
      switch1(newValue){
        //called whenever switch1 changes
        console.log(newValue);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Since the `v-model` of `v-switch` is bound to `switch1` , whenever the switch is toggled on/off the watch handler of `switch1` gets called with the changed `newValue`

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEYJEP#anon-login)

Comment: How to overcome if there are `n` number of switches.

Comment: @MehulPrajapati just extract the switch with a watcher into its own component and reuse the component `n` times

Comment: found another better solution which uses `@change` prop.

Comment: @change is not a better solution, defeates the purpose of Vue

Answer (score 21):

Found another better solution to use `@change` prop, Which calls the method every time the switch is toggled.

```
    <v-switch
        :input-value="true"
        @change="changeState(item.id)"
    ></v-switch>
    <v-switch
        :input-value="true"
        @change="changeState(item.id)"
    ></v-switch>
```

Here's script,

```
methods:{
    changeState(id) {
        console.log("Switch "+id);
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Vuetify 3:

### Template

```
<v-switch
    :model-value="true"
    color="success"
    hide-details
    @change="changeStatus(item)"
></v-switch>
```

### Script

```
methods: {
    changeStatus(item) {
        console.log('item', item)
    }
}
```